# Getting mean and erasing numbers with to much difference

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, filter

So, say I have a list consisting of:
`2231, 2240, 2236, 2238, 7`

Now these numbers come from a sensor, a height sensor, so some numbers can be faulty, like the `7`.

If I want to get a reasonable mean, I would filter out the `7`, how would I do that as an algorithm? Please show understandable code in Python, C++ or even Frink (Which is what I intend to use.)

I thought of using standard deviation, but I have no idea how to implement it.
And Sorry, I couldn't find any code I've tried, I deleted it after it didn't work.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that. I've tried with halfing each number and multiply it by 2, then do crazy stuff with it, but it didn't work for low numbers. I thought of making ifs for each hundred and thousand number, but that doesn't seem practical. I've done some skisses on a paper, they seem good, but don't work.

Comment: the first idea comes to my mind is to set a tolerance value, say 1000. Then removing numbers those are less than the `mean-tolerance` or greater than the `mean+tolerance`

Comment: Yes as Fallen said tolerance is a good idea, we are doing some sort of the same project and we have a 5% tolerance rate so if the next value is not close it will be considered as faulty, but you can work with this tolerance percentage to find what fits you the best

Comment: The cruicial rule is how to mathematically determine that a point shall be excluded. Could be a distance threshold from local average value. Having that rule you could supply it as a predicate to std::remove_if. Least squares could be used to determine the trend.

Comment: you can also consider using median, as it is not affected by such extreme values

Comment: Drew is right that the contributors to this site generally expect you to show us what you've done and ask for pointers, rather than just to ask for code outright.  One easy solution that comes to mind to me is to eliminate numbers that fall outside of twice the standard deviation (less or more depending on whether you are more interested in eliminating false positives or false negatives).

Comment: Yes, I thought of using standard deviation, as I added in my post, but I have no idea how to implement it, so any tips would be great.

Comment: I think what methods to apply depends a lot on what you're measuring, how you're measuring, and the purpose of the values you're looking for. Perhaps you could first discard the physically impossible, then use statistical methods to filter out the implausible.

Comment: Yes, this seems good, since 7 seems a little impossible, I could just get it out, however if it filters out more then it should, then the error is probably not an error. I'll use this for now, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Standard Deviation:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import math

lista = [2231, 2240, 2236, 2238, 7]

newlist = []
mean = 0
newmean = 0
variance = 0

for i in lista:
    mean += i
mean = mean/float(len(lista))

for i in lista:
    variance += (i*i)
variance = variance/float(len(lista))
variance = math.sqrt(variance)

minval = variance - mean
maxval = variance + mean

for i in lista:
    if i >= minval and i <= maxval:
        newlist.append(i)
print newlist

for i in newlist:
    newmean += i
newmean = newmean/float(len(newlist))
print newmean
```

You can skip most of the code if you wish to manually enter in the "minval" and "maxval".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can define an ACCEPTABLE_DIFFERENCE between two readings. If your values can jump from min/max based on the readings, no mean will actually help you.

Here is a sample code in python that illustrates this point:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

ACCEPTABLE_DIFF = 100

arr = [2231, 2240, 2236, 2238, 7]

for index in range(1,len(arr)):
  if (abs(arr[index] - arr[index-1]) > ACCEPTABLE_DIFF):
    del arr[index]


print arr
```

an alternative is using a difference percentage:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

ACCEPTABLE_DIFF_PERC = 5

arr = [2231, 2240, 2236, 2238, 7]

for index in range(1,len(arr)):
  if (abs(arr[index] - arr[index-1]) > (arr[index-1]*ACCEPTABLE_DIFF_PERC/100)):
    del arr[index]


print arr
```

Comment: Yes that's great, but what if arr is `[21231, 22240, 22236, 22304, 7]`, then `ACCEPTABLE_DIFF` should be something like `1000`.

Comment: Your point is valid. Yet this diff is specific for your domain of use and for your sensors used. It could be say 10% of the maximal value. Computing the value on the run is too resource-consuming and offers no additional functionality. It even stabilizes on some mean value and the algorithm would discard valid values when the reading changes!